# How to find the index of the last array element

Tags: arrays, ruby

In a situation where you have to deal with array indices (and can't just use an enumerator), how do you find the *index* of the last element?

These two options come to mind, but I'm hoping there's an answer that is more self documenting (like `Array#last()`, but for the index instead of the element):

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]

# option 1
last_index = a.length - 1

# option 2
last_index = a.rindex { true }
```

Comment: In Ruby, it is rare that you need to use an index alone. Why do you particularly need the index of the last element, and not the size?

Comment: I believe you have a broader issue, and this is just part of what you think is a solution to it. You should rather write that broader issue. Otherwise, this will probably turn out to be [an XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377).

Comment: Most (if not all) methods dealing with array indices accept _negative indices_ which count backward from the end, i.e. `-1` refers to the last element: `a[-1] #=> 3`

Comment: I was just implementing a little interview style problem where the solution requires walking an array of numbers from both ends at once until you find a pair that meet a certain criteria (I can post the code shortly). Using a negative index does sound like a cleaner approach, but then I would have to change how I detect if the two markers meet on the same element. I think there’s a similar issue with using two enumerators (via `index` and `rindex`)

Comment: There is nothing more self documenting than `array.length - 1`. That's the last index of an array in virtually every language. Indexes of an array are *defined* by the range `0..array.length-1`.

Comment: Hi,
this also will give you the last element index `a.index(a[-1])`

Comment: @suhail I'm not sure if that's meant to be a joke, but it's totally wrong and far worse than simply writing `a.length - 1`.  It fails completely if the array contains duplicates, and in the case that it works, it involves a linear scan of the entire array for *no reason*, just to arrive at the number `.length - 1`.

Comment: Hi @meagar I completely agree, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

 def last_index(arr)
   counter = -1
   arr.each do |i| 
      i
      counter += 1 
   end 
   counter
 end
last_index(arr)
```

Comment: This returns the last element `6` but we're interested its index `5`. Also note your parameter name is misleading since you're expected to pass an array.

Comment: Thought he was looking for the last element in the array, edited.

Comment: Unfortunately your edit only works by accident. If you look at the positve indices of `arr`, they are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. So the last element `6` has index 5. e.g. if we have another array of the same size `[1,1,1,1,1,2]`, the last element is `2` but it's index is still `5`.

Comment: Ahhh i read the question wrong. I will edit again when I get a chance.